# splunk query not showing all records when converted in table format

Tags: splunk-query

```
sourcetype=my-job "Get Connection Details" | spath input=Message | search FileName=* | rename event.Values.Connections{}.ClientName as ThirdParty
```

This query returns some N number of records, but as soon as I apply below filter

```
| dedup FileName| table  FileName, ThirdParty | fillnull value=N/A | sort  ThirdParty desc
```

Query shows only N-M records.

Hence it is not showing all the ThirdParty in result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem temporarily by reducing the log file size.